# IntelliJ reorder changes tab by filepath

Tags: intellij-idea, diff

IntelliJ IDEA 12.x orders the diff in the "Changes" tab by filename only, how do you order by the file path?

IE:

```
src/main/a/SomeFile.java
src/main/b/AnotherFile.java
```

Versus the current order

```
src/main/b/AnotherFile.java
src/main/a/SomeFile.java
```

There seems to be no settings for this tab in the settings options.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is "Group by folders" button on the Changes toolbar for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Group by Directory" button (or if you're on a Mac, Command-F9).  This also groups by the submodule your changes are located in.

[image: Group by Directory icon]